# How I can use django ModelForm object and Queryset to do login authentication function

Tags: python, django, http-post

My following question is about how I can develop a function that I can compare a POST request data (`ModelForm`) and existing data of model in `queryset`.

This is mi models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=False, blank=False, default="12345678R")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telefone_number = models.IntegerField()
    user_nick = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="user")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, default="password")
    ticket = models.ManyToManyField(Ticket)
```

forms.py (EmployerLoginForm only to `user_nick` and `password`):

```
class EmployerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"

class EmployerLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ['dni', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'telefone_number', 'ticket']
```

In this case, to develop login function I am using the `EmployerLoginForm` in views.py:

```
_logger = nexus_services_logs.Logging(statics.NEXUS_VIEWS_LOGGING_NAME)
_views_manager_service = nexus_services_views_manager.ViewsManagerService()
_auth = nexus_services_auth.Authentication()

class IndexView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = EmployerLoginForm(request.POST)
        if(_auth.check_model_employer_authentication(form, _logger, _views_manager_service)):
            if(_views_manager_service.validate_form(form, _logger)):
                _views_manager_service.save_form(form, _logger)
            return redirect('employerPortal')
        else:
            return redirect('index')
```

`check_model_employer_authentication(form, _logger, _views_manager_service)` is the function where I want compare form data and queryset. I find the problem when I cannot compare the objects using for loop (in `auth.py`):

```
class Authentication():

    def __init__(self):
        self.employer_exist = False

    def check_model_employer_authentication(self, model, logger, views_manager_service):
        queryset_all_employers = Employee.objects.order_by("id")
        context_exployers = views_manager_service.build_context_queryset_employers(queryset_all_employers) 
        for employer in context_exployers["employers"]:
            if(employer.user_nick == model.user_nick and employer.password == model.password):
                self.employer_exist = True
                logger.info_log("Exist nick with similar password")
                return True
            else:
                logger.error_log("Nick or password not exist or coincidence with object in db")
                return False
```

I have tried using a context but not works.

Comment: What doesnt work? are you facing any error. Where is the traceback?

Comment: yes in the line of if statement: if(employer.user_nick == model.user_nick and employer.password == model.password). I think it is becease the form object can´t obtain user_nick and password.